# Access azure webapp with the CNAME which is behind an Azure Application gateway

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have an azure web app and its corresponding application gateway.
I have created a CNAME and pointed it to the DNS name of the app gateway.

Now when I access the site using the CNAME, it reaches the app gateway and redirects me to the web app(actual web app URL ...azurewebsites.net).

Is it possible that using the CNAME, I should be able to reach the web app i.e. on the address bar it should be displaying the same CNAME to reaching the web app(it should not redirect to the web app)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could configure the custom domain like `sub.example.com` to the web app first, then you could add such custom domain in the **hostnames** of Azure web app service. Once the DNS propagation happens, the CNAME record of the custom domain in the DNS zone should be changed to map the FQDN of the Application gateway like `xxx.cloudapp.net`.

I test this using web app service without HTTPS redirection. `HTTPS Only` is `off`. Azure Application Gateway is also working for HTTP. If you want to use HTTPS for the web app, you need an SSL cert for the custom domain.

[Tutorial: Map an existing custom DNS name to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain)

### Update

In this case, you properly set `HTTPS only` is `on` in the custom domains of Azure web app service. For me, I could still set "Pick up hostname from the backend pool" under the HTTP setting even I do not add the hostnames as my previous reply. The redirection actually is related to the "HTTPS only" under Custom Domain in Azure web app.

Comment: Thank you Nancy. I'll check from myside

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue fixed:
The redirection that was occurring was due to a setting "Pick up hostname from the backend pool" under HTTP setting of application gateway. Removing that setting, using the CNAME we were able to reach the web app but we were getting an error "Too_Many_redirects" and this was resolved once the "HTTPS only" is set to off on the web app under Custom Domain as this redirection was configured at the gateway level.

Comment: For me, I could still set "Pick up hostname from the backend pool" under the HTTP setting even I do not add the hostnames as my previous reply. The redirection actually is related to the "HTTPS only" under Custom Domain in Azure web app. Could you check this on your side? I also add this in my reply.

Comment: Sure. I'll check the setting "Pick up hostname from the backend pool" and will try. Thank you very much

Comment: Have you verified this? If my reply is helpful, you could accept it as an answer.

Comment: It did work. Thank you very much Nancy. Sorry for the late reply.
Unfortunately I'm a new member to the StackOverflow and it says "your response is recorded and but do not change the publicly displayed post score.
Answer Accepted

Comment: Glad to help you.